# How to replace next button with mat-chip in Angular Material stepper?

Tags: html, css

I am using angular material stepper, in the stepper i want to replace next button with mat-chip and act as same functionality as next button.
[Here is angular stepper stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnvplnlyxae?file=app%2Fstepper-editable-example.html)

*This is what i want*:

[image: This is i want]

Comment: Is this really an Angular question? Plain css is your friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you just want the button to look like a material chip (rather than actually be a material chip), you could remove 'mat-button' from the next button and add your own class, e.g. 'next_btn':

```
<button class="next_btn" matStepperNext>Next</button>
```

You can then just style the button so it looks like a chip:

```
button.next_btn {
    padding: 7px 12px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    min-height: 32px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    box-shadow:none;
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;
}

button.next_btn:focus 
{
    outline:none;
}
```

Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g57yss?file=app%2Fstepper-editable-example.css).

Comment: But sir, after click on chip like button ,blue border coming, this is not required.How to fix  this?

Comment: Have updated my answer - let me know if the additional CSS removes the blue border.

Answer (score 0):

How about inserting the button inside the chip? and managing the look... take a look here for [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnvplnlyxae?file=app%2Fstepper-editable-example.html)

**HTML**:

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip><button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button></mat-chip>
  <mat-chip><button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button></mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**CSS**:

```
mat-chip{padding:0;}
```